# Mathematical Modeling - Matlab ode45-for loop

Tags: matlab, math, modeling, ode45

I need to make a code to get phase portraits for a mathematical model with "history". I will explain after the code.

```
close all;
clear all;

times = 1990:1:2015;
hold on

b=zeros(1,26); %75-2000 per 5 years
b(1:5)=0.0358;
b(6:10)=0.0339;
b(11:15)=0.0311;
b(16:20)=0.0275;
b(21:26)=0.0249;

m=zeros(1,26); %90-2015 per 5 years
m(1:5)=0.008;
m(6:10)=0.0031;
m(11:15)=0.0137;
m(16:20)=0.0147;
m(21:26)=0.0125;

l=zeros(1,26); %90-2015 per 5 years
l(1:5)=0.015;
l(6:10)=0.031;
l(11:15)=0.026;
l(16:20)=0.015;
l(21:26)=0.014;

u=zeros(1,26); %90-2015 per 5 years
u(1:5)=0.04;
u(6:10)=0.02;
u(11:15)=0.038;
u(16:20)=0.05;
u(21:26)=0.035;

S=zeros(1,26);
I=zeros(1,26);
N=zeros(1,26);
S(1)=18442000;
I(1)=186000; %1990
N(1)=18628000;
P=zeros(1,26); %15 years before S
P(1:5)=12788000; 
P(6:10)=14731000;
P(11:15)=16968000;
P(16:20)=19696000;
P(21:26)=22893000;

for i=1:26
    [time, xy] = ode45('test_func',times,[S(i) I(i) N(i) P(i) b(i) m(i) l(i) u(i)]);
    plot(time,xy(:,1),'-g',time,xy(:,2),'-r',time,xy(:,3),'-b');
end

function rhs = test_func(t,xx)

S = xx(1);
I = xx(2);
N = xx(3);
P = xx(4);
b = xx(5);
m = xx(6);
l = xx(7);
u = xx(8);

Sdot=b*P-m*S-l*S*I; 
Idot=l*S*I-(m+u)*I;
Ndot=Sdot+Idot;

rhs = [Sdot; Idot; Ndot; P; b; m; l; u;];

end
```

List of details:

- `S`=healthy population
- `I`=infected population
- `N`=total population
- `b`=birth rate (15 years prior to `S`)
- `m`=mortality rate
- `l`=infection chance on contact
- `u`=death rate due to disease

`P` and `S` represent the same thing just in different time periods (`P`=15 years prior to `S`), also all `P` values are given.

The code needs to return the phase portrait of `S`,`I` and `N`. I am definitely not 100% sure my code is right for what I aim to do but this is what I came up with. Currently the code runs but never ends. Any suggestions on my code or help to fix the error are welcome.

I was also thinking of adding the following inside the for loop right between the ode45 and plot, if necessary:

```
if i<26
    xy(i+1)=S(i+1);
    xy(i+27)=I(i+1);
    xy(i+53)=N(i+1);
end
```

Comment: The error message arises because the dimensions of `rhs` and `xx` are not the same in `test_func`. You can make the dimensions the same with 2 revisions:  
1) The dimensions of `Sdot`, `Idot`, and `Ndot` are each 1 x 26 because `b`, `m`, `l`, and `u` are 1 x 26. You should only use the relevant component from each of these vectors.  
2) You should provide `P` to the `test_func` function the same way you provide `b`, `m`, `l`, and `u`. Otherwise, you will need to define `Pdot`.

Comment: i made changed to the above post so that the dimensions match but as i said above still not the result i hoped for

Comment: Hey. I tested out a cleaned up version of your code. It takes an unreasonably long time to run. I think it's because there's a problem in `test_func`. I suspect that there's a problem with the units of the quantities.

Comment: `Idot` depends on `l*S*I`, which is around `0.015*18442000*186000` in 1990. An infection rate of 51.4 billion/year sounds too high to me.

Comment: Hi, first of all i would like to thank you for trying to help. So I divided all population values by 1000 and it still takes time to run, i will try dividing more and just multiply the axis in the graph by that amount. What do you think about the part i edited at the end of my original post?

Comment: Also i think i made a mistake with 'l'. Now i adjusted it to 0.001 at all times.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think the for-loop is necessary for using ode45.

Comment: But how else would I write it so that b,m,u, and P changes at different times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ode45` is intended to solve ordinary differential equations. An ordinary differential equation problem setup will have some essential components.

```
xdot = f(t, x)
```

is the differential equation.

```
x(t=t0) = x0
```

is the initial condition.

`t` is the independent variable and corresponds to `time` in your implementation.

`x` is the dependent variable and corresponds to `S`, `I`, and `N` in your implentation.

The `t0` and `x0` in the initial condition correspond with `times(1)=1990` and `S(1)`, `I(1)`, and `N(1)`.

The remaining task is to define `f` in a way that MATLAB understands. Once you have all these components, `ode45` is ready to use.

Defining `f` is probably the most difficult part. In your implementation, it corresponds with `test_func` and the additional parameters required for `test_func` (`P`, `b`, `m`, `l`, `u`).

It's important to note that in your situation, these parameters also depend on time. Perhaps it's clearer to write them as `P(t)`, `b(t)`, `m(t)`, `l(t)`, and `u(t)`.

In this case, it's probably helpful to take a look at the `interp1` function, which is a built-in linear interpolation function. Given your data points, MATLAB can estimate the value of `P(t)`, `b(t)`, `m(t)`, `l(t)`, and `u(t)`, when `t` isn't every 5th year.

```
function q41895153_ode45()

time_range = 1990:0.1:2015;
time_hist = 1990:5:2015;

b=zeros(1,6); %75-2000 per 5 years
b(1)=0.0358;
b(2)=0.0339;
b(3)=0.0311;
b(4)=0.0275;
b(5)=0.0249;
b(6)=0.0249;

m=zeros(1,6); %90-2015 per 5 years
m(1)=0.008;
m(2)=0.0031;
m(3)=0.0137;
m(4)=0.0147;
m(5)=0.0125;
m(6)=0.0125;

l=zeros(1,6); %90-2015 per 5 years
%{
l(1)=0.015;
l(2)=0.031;
l(3)=0.026;
l(4)=0.015;
l(5)=0.014;
l(6)=0.014;
%}

l(1)=0.001;
l(2)=0.001;
l(3)=0.001;
l(4)=0.001;
l(5)=0.001;
l(6)=0.001;

u=zeros(1,6); %90-2015 per 5 years
u(1)=0.04;
u(2)=0.02;
u(3)=0.038;
u(4)=0.05;
u(5)=0.035;
u(6)=0.035;

S0=18442;
I0=186; %1990
P=zeros(1,6); %15 years before S
P(1)=12788; 
P(2)=14731;
P(3)=16968;
P(4)=19696;
P(5)=22893;
P(6)=22893;

[time, xy] = ode45(@test_func,time_range,[S0 I0],odeset(),time_hist,P,b,m,l,u);

S = xy(:,1)
I = xy(:,2)
N = S + I

plot(time,xy);

end

function rhs = test_func(t,xx,time_hist,P,b,m,l,u)

S = xx(1);
I = xx(2);

% Interpolate to find b(t), m(t), l(t), u(t), P(t)
bt = interp1(time_hist,b,t);
mt = interp1(time_hist,m,t);
lt = interp1(time_hist,l,t);
ut = interp1(time_hist,u,t);
Pt = interp1(time_hist,P,t);

Sdot=bt*Pt-mt*S-lt*S*I; 
Idot=lt*S*I-(mt+ut)*I;

rhs = [Sdot; Idot];

end
```

Comment: Thank you! It works much better than what I had. To be honest I didn't know about the interp1 function. Just need to find out what I have wrong S goes straight to 0 and it will be done. Probably something wrong with the values I have.